# TableView not showing data

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I can't seem to figure out why my cell fields don't have data in them.
This is my TableView. The cell fields are linked in the cell class. The cell identifier is "cell".

when i have it "print" the PFObject i get:

```
["Scott"] ["Hoffman"]
["Scott", "Johnny"] ["Hoffman", "Apple"]
["Scott", "Johnny", "dsgfdsfg"] ["Hoffman", "Apple", "dsdsgf"]
```

class ParticipantTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
let userLabel = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
var firstname = [String]()
var lastname = [String]()
var laps = [String]()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   // self.navigationItem.title = userLabel

   self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated:true);

    // Query database for school
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    let userSchool = currentUser!.objectForKey("school") as! String
    print(userSchool)

    //Query database for Participants
   let query = PFQuery(className:"Participant")
   query.whereKey("school", equalTo:userSchool)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {
            for object:PFObject in objects {
                self.firstname.append(object["firstname"] as! String)
                self.lastname.append(object["lastname"] as! String)

             //   self.laps.append(object["laps"] as! String)

             print(self.firstname, self.lastname)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
   // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:ParticipantTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParticipantTableViewCell
    // Configure the Cell


    cell.firstnameLabel.text = self.firstname[indexPath.row] as String;
    cell.lastnameLabel.text = self.lastname[indexPath.row] as String;
  //myCell.lapLabel.text = self.laps[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: If you return `0` in your `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` method, any cell will be rendered

Comment: when i change the [tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int ] to 1, i get an error: fatal error: Array index out of range,  for this line: cell.firstnameLabel.text = self.firstname[indexPath.row] as String;

Comment: That's because you are rendering the cell before the names are loaded, you should return there the count of objects in the array, (e.g. `self.firstname.count`) in the numberOfRows method

Comment: Ah, got it now, Thank you

Comment: I'll post it as an answer cause I like points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are returning `0` in your `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` method, no cell will be rendered.

You should return the number of cell to be rendered, which in your case is the number of strings in you `firstname`array. So your method would look like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return firstname.count
}
```